# Data segmentation and optimization for Multi-threaded/Multi-core use (In Python)

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I have written a very basic algorithm, that counts the amount of times sub-string appears in a string.

The algorithm is given:

- **seq** - a string sequence
- **k** - length of a sub-string
- **L** - a window of a string to search in
- **t** - times that sub-string, length **k** has to be present to be added to results

---

```
from collections import defaultdict
import concurrent.futures


def kmer_clumps(seq, k, L, t):
    """Returns a set of L-t kmers that form a clump. If a kmer of length [k] apperas [t] times in window [L], it is added to a set"""
    print("Starting a job")
    clump_dict = defaultdict(list)
    clumps = set()

    for pos in range(len(seq) - k + 1):
        current_pos = seq[pos:pos + k]
        clump_dict[current_pos].append(pos)

        if len(clump_dict[current_pos]) >= t:
            if ((clump_dict[current_pos][-1] + (k - 1)) - clump_dict[current_pos][-t]) < L:
                clumps.add(current_pos)
    if clumps:
        return clumps
    else:
        return None
```

---

[image]

---

Running this algorithm in one thread/core is easy, just pass all of the parameters and it scans the string and returns a list.

Now, this is a perfect candidate for running on multiple cores as sometimes I need to provide a large amount of data to this algorithm (text file 20mb+ in size or even more).

Below, I have used Python's `import multiprocessing` and/or `import concurrent.futures`, but this does not really matter as the question is: what is the best way of splitting the data to be passed to multiple threads/cores to avoid duplicate data, large amounts of memory usage, etc... I am hoping that people can share their experience in preparing data in this manner and best practices for this.

```
seq = "CGGACTCGACAGATGTGAAGAACGACAATGTGAAGACTCGACACGACAGAGTGAAGAGAAGAGGAAACATTGTAA"
k = 5
L = 50
t = 4
cores = 2


def sub_seq_clumps_multicore_job(seq, k, L, t, cores=1):
    seqLength = len(seq)
    if cores == 1:
        print("Using only 1 core as specified or data is to small.")
        return kmer_clumps(seq, k, L, t)

    else:
        print("Preparing data...")

        # Basic logic to split the data to provide to multiple jobs/threads
        jobSegments = seqLength // cores
        extraSegments = seqLength % cores
        overlapSize = (L // cores)

        # Creating multiple parts from a single string and adding same arguments to all
        # Amount of parts is based on core/thread count
        parts = []
        for part in range(0, seqLength, jobSegments + extraSegments):
            tmpList = [seq[part:part + jobSegments +
                           extraSegments + overlapSize + 1], k, L, t]
            parts.append(tmpList)

        print(f"Processing data on {cores} cores...")
        resultSet = set()

        # Starting jobs/threads by passing all parts to a thread pool
        with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executer:
            jobs = [
                executer.submit(kmer_clumps, *sec) for sec in parts
            ]

            # Just collecting results
            for f in concurrent.futures.as_completed(jobs):
                resultSet.update(f.result())

        # Returning collected results, which are sub-strings of length k,
        # that were found in all windows length L
        return resultSet


print(sub_seq_clumps_multicore_job(seq, k, L, t, cores))
```

Some sample output:

**Data, segmented and passed to `kmer_clumps(seq, k, L, t)` to run on 1 core/thread:**

```
"CGGACTCGACAGATGTGAAGAACGACAATGTGAAGACTCGACACGACAGAGTGAAGAGAAGAGGAAACATTGTAA", 5, 50, 4
```

**Data, segmented and passed to `kmer_clumps(seq, k, L, t)` to run on 2 core/thread:**

```
Thread 1:
['CGGACTCGACAGATGTGAAGAACGACAATGTGAAGACTCGACACGACAGAGTGAAGAGAAGAGG', 5, 50, 4]
Thread 2:
['CGACACGACAGAGTGAAGAGAAGAGGAAACATTGTAA', 5, 50, 4]
```

**Data, segmented and passed to `kmer_clumps(seq, k, L, t)` to run on 4 core/thread:**

```
Thread 1:
['CGGACTCGACAGATGTGAAGAACGACAATGTGAA', 5, 50, 4]
Thread 2:
['ACGACAATGTGAAGACTCGACACGACAGAGTGAA', 5, 50, 4]
Thread 3:
['ACGACAGAGTGAAGAGAAGAGGAAACATTGTAA', 5, 50, 4]
Thread 4:
['GAAACATTGTAA', 5, 50, 4]]
```

---

---

**Results in running time, when reading a huge data file (4.5 MB):**

```
File reading complete!
Using only 1 core as specified or data is to small.
Starting a job

real    0m4.536s
```

---

```
File reading complete!
Preparing data...
Processing data on 2 cores...
Starting a job
Starting a job

real    0m2.438s
```

---

```
File reading complete!
Preparing data...
Processing data on 4 cores...
Starting a job
Starting a job
Starting a job
Starting a job

real    0m1.413s
```

---

```
File reading complete!
Preparing data...
Processing data on 6 cores...
Starting a job
Starting a job
Starting a job
Starting a job
Starting a job
Starting a job

real    0m1.268s
```

Because of the nature of the algorithm, when running on multiple threads/cores there is more data generated as we need to make sure we cover the whole data string and take a window L into the account. So there are data overlaps happening:

Let's take two examples:

**Running on 2 cores:**
[image]

**Running on 4 cores:**
[image]
[image]
[image]

With this post I have two goals:

1) To have experienced people look at it and suggest any improvements to how to segment the data for threading like that, to avoid data duplicates, memory overload, etc... any suggestions would be very helpful.

2) To learn from amazing people and so others can learn from this example.

Thank you all very much!

Comment: _I am not including this algorithm to avoid confusion. It has been tested and it works as expected._ - Fine; but what if a reviewer wants to execute your code (potentially with different segmentation)?

Comment: @Reinderien you are right.

Answer (score 1):

### Type hints

At a guess, this:

```
def kmer_clumps(seq, k, L, t):
```

can become

```
def kmer_clumps(seq: Sequence[str], k: int, l: int, t: int) -> Set[str]:
```

It's somewhat more self-documenting, and helps your IDE with static analysis and autocompletion.

p.s. There's nothing wrong with returning an empty set. That's much more preferable than returning `None`. People iterating over the returned set often won't need to change their code for an empty set, but *would* need to change their code for a `None`.

### Logging

```
print("Starting a job")
```

can benefit from the (even simple) use of https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/logging.html#module-email

### Global constants

...such as

```
k = 5
L = 50
t = 4
cores = 2
```

should be ALL_CAPS.

### Variable names

`seqLength` should be snake_case, i.e. `set_length`; and so on for your other variables.

### Generators

```
    parts = []
    for part in range(0, seqLength, jobSegments + extraSegments):
        tmpList = [seq[part:part + jobSegments +
                       extraSegments + overlapSize + 1], k, L, t]
        parts.append(tmpList)
```

can be cleaned up by factoring it out into a generator function:

```
def make_part_list(...):
    for part in range(0, seqLength, jobSegments + extraSegments):
        tmpList = [seq[part:part + jobSegments +
                       extraSegments + overlapSize + 1], k, L, t]
        yield tmpList
        # or if you don't want nested lists...
        yield from tmpList

# ...
parts = tuple(make_part_list(...))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input! This code is mostly draft, so 'Global constants', for example, were just for testing porpoise so people can try running the code. While you provided very interesting suggestions, I was more interested in discussing how we can optimize segmentation of the data, a string of text in this case, before we split it into multiple threads/cores. this code works just fine and does what I need it to do. I could not find any good information about how to segment/split data for multiprocessing.

Comment: In some cases you just need to do multiple things, which are not really connected ore semi-connected in parallel. This is easier. But in this case we have one single peace of data that we need to process and the result is a combination of all the 'findings' from all threads. I was wondering if there was a better way to approach data segmentation/splitting.